# my painting canvas with opencv couldn't change color of pencil

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# creating 600*600 image with 3 colors in it
img = np.ones((601, 601, 3), np.uint8) * 255


# classes
class Tools:
    def __init__(self,points:list,color) -> None:
        self.points=points
        self.color=color
        cv2.rectangle(img,self.points[0],self.points[1],self.color,-1)


color=None
# functions
def change_Tool(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global color
    if event==cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        if x in range(pencil.points[0][0],pencil.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=pencil.color
        elif x in range(eraser.points[0][0],eraser.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=eraser.color
        elif x in range(green.points[0][0],green.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=green.color
        elif x in range(red.points[0][0],red.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=red.color
        elif x in range(blue.points[0][0],blue.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):color=blue.color


def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global color
    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),20,color,-1)
        

# Variables
# eraser, pencil, green, red, blue
pencil=Tools([(5, 560),(123, 594)],(0,0,0))

eraser=Tools([(123, 560),(241, 594)],(255,255,255))

green=Tools([(241, 560),(359, 594)],(0,255,0))

red=Tools([(359, 560),(477, 594)],(255,0,0))

blue=Tools([(477, 560),(595, 594)],(0,0,255))

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', change_Tool)
cv2.setMouseCallback('image', draw_circle)

while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF ==27:break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

First I try to create 600*600 image then I create `Tool` class to declare pencil and draw circle function and variables.

I declare an area for each tool that when I R-click on them the color changes to that object's color.

Then I declare mouse call backs.

I just get black color when I L-click and when I R-click it doesn't make any change and I don't know how to fix this. Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out what the problem is :
Because I have specified two different mouse callback functions using cv2.setMouseCallback() on the same named window Because of this, the second callback function defined (in this case 'draw_circle') overwrites the first callback function 'change_color'.

So I mixed up this two functions and run it again and I saw the problem was solved

Here's the fixed code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#creating 600*600 image with 3 colors in it
img = np.ones((601, 601, 3), np.uint8) * 255


#classes
class Tools:
    def __init__(self,points:list,color) -> None:
        self.points=points
        self.color=color
        cv2.rectangle(img,self.points[0],self.points[1],self.color,-1)



#Variables
# eraser, pencil,green,red,blue
pencil=Tools([(5, 560),(123, 594)],(0,0,0))

eraser=Tools([(123, 560),(241, 594)],(255,255,255))

green=Tools([(241, 560),(359, 594)],(0,255,0))

red=Tools([(359, 560),(477, 594)],(255,0,0))

blue=Tools([(477, 560),(595, 594)],(0,0,255))



color=(255,0,0)
#functions
def change_Tool(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global color
    if event==cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        if x in range(pencil.points[0][0],pencil.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=pencil.color
        elif x in range(eraser.points[0][0],eraser.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=eraser.color
        elif x in range(green.points[0][0],green.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=green.color
        elif x in range(red.points[0][0],red.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):
            color=red.color
        elif x in range(blue.points[0][0],blue.points[1][0]) and y in range(560,594):color=blue.color
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),10,color,-1)
            
                

cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.setMouseCallback('image',change_Tool)


while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) and 0xFF ==27:break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Now I have a simple painting canvas which have four different color and an eraser